# saving an array of dates to the database in rails, each date to a different row in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to implement a booking system for multiple dates.

The user picks dates to book using jquery multiDatesPicker:

```
<%= form_for @showing, :html => { multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :date %>
  <%= f.submit "Next", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

<script>
  $(function() {
    $('#showing_date').multiDatesPicker()({ 
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
  });
</script>
```

Currently when clicking submit only the first date that is picked gets saved to the database. How can I save an array of dates and then save each date separately in a different row in the table?

Comment: How will you get array of dates? User will select only one date right?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check how your data look like first, you can use gem [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and add `binding.pry` to your controller. Then you will have idea how to solve this problem. If you don't get it then let me know, thanks :)